# How to change the width and height of a DIV using variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the width and height of a DIV dynamically using variables in javascript.  My code below is not working for me.

```
 div_canvas.setAttribute('style', "width: '+w_resized+'px");
 div_canvas.setAttribute('style', "height: '+h_resized+'px");
```

Where w_resized and h_resized are variables.

Comment: `div_canvas.style.width = w_resized + 'px';`

Comment: `div_canvas.style.height = h_resized + 'px';`

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using setAttribute will override the previously provided values.... you can use the style property like

```
div_canvas.style.width = w_resized + 'px';
div_canvas.style.height = h_resized + 'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```
 div_canvas.style.width = w_resized+'px';
 div_canvas.style.height = h_resized+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

Return the width property:

```
object.style.width
```

Set the width property:

```
object.style.width="auto|length|%|initial|inherit"
```

same for height

Answer (score 0):

```
//HEIGHT
function upBig(id,ud) {
       var div=document.getElementById(id);
       var h=parseInt(div.style.height)+ud;
       if (h>=1){
          div.style.height = h + "px";
       }
}

//WIDTH

function upBig2(id,ud) {
       var div=document.getElementById(id);
       var h=parseInt(div.style.width)+ud;
       if (h>=1){
          div.style.width = h + "px";
       }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1cotj5o5/65/